# How to add support for Shallow ETag in ResponseEntity Spring Java

Tags: spring, etag, httpentity, response-entity

I understand that we can create the filter for Shallow E tag in spring. However, i am looking if there is an easier way to do it.
I am using HttpEntity in my code for getting the response.
The code looks like this

```
return ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .eTag(getETag(preloadMap))
                    .body(preloadMap);
```

However, I am looking forward to options of changing this etag to Shallow etag in a simpler way.

Comment: So instead of registering a filter, which does this automatically, you want to re-invent the wheel? How is that easier?

Answer (score 0):

I think using spring filter is the easiest way to implement shallow etag. Within three lines it's done.

```
@Configuration
public MyConfigClass () {
    @Bean
    public Filter shallowEtagHeaderFilter() {
        return new ShallowEtagHeaderFilter();
    }
}
```

This filter is in charge of generating a hash response and adding it up to the etag header.

It also verifies if the created hash matches with the existing etag from "if-none-match". If both are equal it returns 304 Not modified. Otherwise it just returns 200 OK.

Comment: Just to confirm, this will only work on GET and HEAD HTTP methods. Spring removed PUT POST and DELETE methods from verifying ETag `If-Match` and other validations for Pre Conditions ?